# Excel VBA - Creating buttons dynamically with code assigned

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to create some buttons dynamically, and assign code to them.

The following code works

```
Dim MyR As Range, MyB As OLEObject
Dim MyR_T As Long, MyR_L As Long


    Set MyR = Cells(i + 1, 11) 'just an example - you get that from your own script
    MyR_T = MyR.Top         'capture positions
    MyR_L = MyR.Left        '...
    'create button
    Set MyB = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)


    'set main button properties
    With MyB

        .Name = "MyPrecodedButton"     'important - code must exist ... see below
        .Object.Caption = "MyCaption"
        .Top = MyR_T
        .Left = MyR_L
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 18
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True            'or false as per your taste


    End With
```

It creates the buttons within my loop. However,  I want to assign something to the on click, so I use the following code

```
Dim MyR As Range, MyB As OLEObject
Dim MyR_T As Long, MyR_L As Long


    Set MyR = Cells(i + 1, 11) 'just an example - you get that from your own script
    MyR_T = MyR.Top         'capture positions
    MyR_L = MyR.Left        '...
    'create button
    Set MyB = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)


    'set main button properties
    With MyB
        .OnAction = "interpHere"
        .Name = "MyPrecodedButton"     'important - code must exist ... see below
        .Object.Caption = "MyCaption"
        .Top = MyR_T
        .Left = MyR_L
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 18
        .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        .PrintObject = True            'or false as per your taste


    End With

    Sub interpHere()
        MsgBox "hi"
    End Sub
```

I have basically added **.OnAction = "interpHere"** but when I run it, I get an error, unable to set the onaction property.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is all your code in a **Standard Module** ??

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/LFINtNC.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
Sub CreateButtons()
  Dim btn As Button
  ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
  Dim t As Range
  For i = 2 To 6 Step 2
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3)
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
      .OnAction = "interpHere"
      .Caption = "Btn " & i
      .Name = "Btn" & i
    End With
  Next i
End Sub

Sub interpHere()
    MsgBox "hi"
End Sub
```